# I am using Oracle EBS R2 Is there any solution to get the IP address of Client machine

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle12c, oracleforms, oracle-ebs

I have tried the below but it is based on user. I am trying to get the client machine IP address no matter which user is connected to that.

```
SELECT distinct 
       c.CLIENTIP
  FROM v$process a, 
       v$session b, 
       fnd_logins c, 
       fnd_user d
 WHERE a.pid = c.pid
   AND d.user_id = c.user_id
   and d.user_name = '&User_name'
   AND a.addr = b.paddr
   AND c.end_time IS NULL;
```

Comment: You should ask this question on Serverfault.

Comment: You should set the [client_info](https://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=newest&q=user%3a5841306%20Dbms_Application_Info.Set_Client_Info) from somewhere within your application. You might also use the client's IP address as the client's info, but I recommend that be sure they're not dynamic.

Answer (score 0):

You can remove the filter and include the username in the select. You don’t need the joins the fixed views (v$…) so I’ve removed them. I don’t know the data model, there may well be other columns you’re interested in too.

This will return the name and client IPs for logged in users

```
SELECT distinct 
        d.user_name
       ,c.CLIENTIP
FROM fnd_logins c, 
       fnd_user d
WHERE d.user_id = c.user_id
AND c.end_time IS NULL;
```

Comment: Andrew Sayer, I don't want to get the IP based on user login but the client machine IP address. no matter which login.

Comment: The query gives you every IP address for connected users. You can further remove the `end_time` filter if you want to include logged out sessions.

Comment: I have tried this but it won't work because when I logged IN with username of my colleague on my PC it is showing the IP address of his PC not mine.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the SQL from blitz report [FND User Login History](https://www.enginatics.com/reports/fnd-user-login-history/), showing the data for all users and additional joins from fnd_logins to other FND data.

Answer (score 0):

Andrew's query should give you the query without constraining the user.

Section 3 of MOS Note 2069190.1 and the associated zip has some example queries of fnd logins and icx session tables that would be useful for this type of query as well as the joins between tables.

A couple of things to keep in mind when querying IP addresses in E-Business Suite:

- Client IP addresses are currently only captured in the FND Login table for Forms  not for HTML (self-service) pages (although that's likely to change in a future release).
- IP addresses for HTML pages can be found in the Apache access logs - but it's difficult to associate those with specific users.
- If you have a load balancer or reverse proxy in front of your E-Business Suite you will likely be getting the IP address of that machine, unless you're passing the client IP through - but that's another question.